# Parsing an XML response with namespaces

Tags: php, xml, parsing, response

I'm getting an XML response that I cannot parse. Here's the thing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Exception occurred</faultstring>
            <faultactor>https://services.lso.com/partnershippingservices/v1_5/PricingService.asmx</faultactor>
            <detail>
                <webServiceException xmlns="https://services.lso.com/WebServiceException/v1">
                    <code>600121</code>
                    <action>To zip code is outside of service area.</action>
                </webServiceException>
            </detail>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

It's the response when an error occurs. What I want to get is the values of both code and action.

I know how to handle the response when the request was correctly processed, but I can't do much when an error is returned.

Just to give you an idea, this is what I'm doing with the response I can handle:

```
$responseRate = simplexml_load_string($xmlRateResponse);
$getTotalCharge = $responseRate->children('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')
                    ->Body->children()
                    ->EstimatePriceResponse;
$totalCharge = (float)$getTotalCharge->EstimatePriceResult->TotalCharge;
echo $totalCharge;
```

With this, I can display the rate that is returned.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you're using [`SoapClient`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) I recommend you save yourself some pain and suffering and take a look at [`wsdl2phpgenerator`](https://github.com/wsdl2phpgenerator/wsdl2phpgenerator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, here's a solution.

```
$xmlResponse = new SimpleXMLElement($errorResponse);
$xmlResponse->registerXPathNamespace('soap','http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
$result=$xmlResponse->xpath('//soap:Fault');
foreach ($result as $body) {
    echo $body->detail->webServiceException->code . "<br>";
    echo $body->detail->webServiceException->action . "<br>";
}
```

This is going to return "`600121`" and "`To zip code is outside of service area.`", which is what I want.